# Product of Borel and non-Borel set

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

It is true that product of Borel and non-Borel sets is non-Borel set?
More precisely, I would like to know if $V $×$ \{1\}$ is Borel, where $V$ is Vitali set.

Answer (score 3):

It is well known that for a Borel set $M \subset \Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^m$ the "sections"

$$
M_x =\{y\in \Bbb{R}^m \mid (x,y)\in M\},\\
M^y =\{x\in \Bbb{R}^n\mid (x,y)\in M\}
$$
are Borel measurable for all $x\in \Bbb{R}^n,y\in \Bbb{R}^m$. To see this, show that the class of all such sets forms a sigma algebra an contains the open sets.

Using this property, it is easy to see that if $M,N$ are **nonempty** and if $M\times N$ is Borel, then so are $M,N$.

Comment: Thank you. But I still cannot see, if   $M×N$ is Borel or not,  when $M$ is and $N$ is not Borel.

Comment: @compatibilizator: Assume $M \times N$ is Borel. By what I wrote above, you know that $(M \times N)_x$ is Borel for every $x$. Now choose any $x \in M$ then you have $(M \times N)_x = N$, which is not Borel, a contradiction. Hence, $M\times N $ can not be Borel if $N$ is not.